# why this command doesn't work on windows xp?

Tags: windows

I can see that I can do this: please note that part of path use forward slash and part of uses back slash.

```
cd  C:\a\b/c/d/
```

but this is not working?

```
 type C:\a\b/c/d/readme.txt
```

doesn't work (file exist I that path)

Comment: Looks like it is a bug.  There is a detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523708/why-does-the-cmd-exe-shell-on-windows-fail-with-paths-using-a-forward-slash

Comment: why not use all \  like you're meant to and then you'll see the directory or file if it exists

Comment: / may work most of the time, but \ is the correct or proper Windows method of showing and working with paths.